# error: bundling failed: "Unable to resolve module `react-native/Libraries/Renderer/src/renderers/native/ReactNativePropRegistry

Tags: react-native

Building fails after adding navigation and a drawer to my components. using

```
import { Drawer, View} from 'native-base'
import { Navigator } from 'react-native'
```

Below are my dependencies.

```
"dependencies": {
        "native-base": "2.1.5",
        "react": "15.6.1",
        "react-native": "0.46.1",
        "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.10"
      }
```

I have tried all the steps suggested in response body[ Red Screen ] but no luck.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`native-base@2.1.5` is not compatible with `react-native@0.46`, just upgrade to `2.2.1` can solve it.

See https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/commit/3a4db18ee31c89c419b578dbad9ca306e9a56058, the commit log is not clear.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Jacky,. I have tried this but the packager runs and bundles the index.android.js. Then app freezes and becomes unresponsive.

Comment: Each time I add `import { Drawer } from 'native-base` The app fails with error ** requiring unknown module "react native" found here [link](https://github.com/start-react/native-starter-kit/issues/55)

Comment: For this problem, can you try to remove node_modules (and remove yarn.lock if exists) and then `npm install`?

NOTE: `react-native@0.46` requires `react@16.0.0-alpha.12`, and `native-base@2.2.1` requires `react@>=16.0.0-alpha.3`, can you upgrade to `react@16.0.0-alpha.12`?